# CMake error while running tar

Tags: cmake

I am trying to copy a directory using a CMake script.

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar czf "${name}.orig.tar.gz" "${folder}" 
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debian)
```

but it is throwing an error.

```
CMake Error: archive_write_header: Can't translate pathname 'files/osgModels/textures/índice.jpeg' to UTF-8
```

Now I end up with an archive which doesn't contain all the files.

However I can successfully create the archive when running tar independently, i.e. not using CMake.

Comment: What OS and what version of CMake?

Comment: OS is ubunut 14.04 LTS  and cmake version is 2.8.12.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're seeing this [CMake bug](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14934) which was resolved after version 2.8.12.2.  I'm not sure whether the fix made it into 3.0.0 or if it was 3.0.1, but either way, if you update CMake to the current version, you should see the problem disappear.

(I expect the `í` character of `índice` is the problem here)

Comment: You could always invoke tar directly from the `execute_process` call, but that's not going to be cross-platform in the same way that `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E tar` is.